# Understanding the calculation in MDX

Tags: mdx, mdx-query

I would like to understand how the cube calculates values at different levels.

I have defined Calc as Calc = sum(Y over 12 months including current month)/sum(X over 12 months excluding current month)only for the month in the cube.

The values in month match the expected values when calculated manually. But I don't understand how the cube interprets this formula at the quarter and year level. I am not able to get the same values as in calc column when calculating manually.

Can someone explain me?Thanks.

[image: Sample Cube data]

Comment: Please provide the MDX

Comment: Here it is :                                                                                         Calc =                                                                                             sum( [Report Period].[Report Periods].currentmember.Lag(11) : [Report Period].[Report Periods].currentmember,([Measures].[Y],[Categories].[Category].&[G]))
 /
 sum( [Report Period].[Report Periods].currentmember.Lag(12) : [Report Period].[Report Periods].currentmember.lag(1),[Measures].[X]) * 100

Comment: @GregGalloway, I have added the formula. Can you pls take a look?Thanks!

Comment: I assume it is doing Lag 11 quarters or lag 11 years. Right?